# Non-Abelian anomaly: why does non-Hermitian operator have complete basis of eigenvectors?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, linear-algebra, topology, quantum-anomalies

In section 13.3 of his book [1], Nakahara computes the non-Abelian anomaly for a chiral Weyl fermion coupled to a gauge field by making use of an operator
$$
\mathrm{i}\hat{D} = \mathrm{i}\gamma^\mu (\partial_\mu+\mathrm{i}\mathcal{A}_\mu \mathcal{P}_+) = \left(\begin{matrix}0 & \mathrm{i}\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu P_- \\ \mathrm{i}\gamma^\mu\nabla_\mu P_+ & 0\end{matrix}\right),\tag{13.43}
$$
where $P_{\pm} = \frac{1}{2}(1+\gamma^5)$ are the chirality projection operators. Importantly, this operator is non-Hermitian, so its left and right eigenvectors may differ. These are defined as
\begin{align}
&\mathrm{i}\hat{D}\psi_i = \lambda_i\psi_i, \tag{13.44a}\newline\\
&\chi^\dagger_i(\mathrm{i}\overset{\leftarrow}{\hat{D}}) = \lambda_i \chi^\dagger_i, && (\mathrm{i}\hat{D})^\dagger\chi_i = \bar{\lambda}_i \chi_i. \tag{13.44b}
\end{align}
Nakahara then claims that these eigenvectors are complete, i.e. that
$$
\sum_i \psi_i\chi_i^\dagger = 1.
$$
How do we know this to be true? $\mathrm{i} \hat{D}$ is not Hermitian, so the usual theorems don't apply.

---

[1] M. Nakahara, *Geometry, topology, and physics*, 2nd edition, Taylor & Francis, 2003

Answer (score 0):

Consider a finite-dimensional non-Hermitian  matrix ${\bf M}$ acting on a space $V$. Although such a matrix is not
*guaranteed* to be diagonalizable, it *will*  be in the generic case in which  all its eigenvalues are distinct. It then possesses complete sets of left and right eigenvectors ${\bf u}_n$, ${\bf v}_n$ obeying
$$
{\bf M}{\bf u}_n= \lambda_n {\bf u}_n,\nonumber\\
{\bf v}_n^\dagger {\bf M}= \lambda_n {\bf v}_n^\dagger.\nonumber
$$
We have not distinguished between the  left  and right eigenvalues because   the two sets of eigenvalues   coincide:  they are determined by the same characteristic equation.
Although   a  right (left) eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_n$ is  no longer orthogonal to all right  (left) eigenvectors with a different eigenvalue $\lambda_m$, it remains true that  a {\it left/} eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_n$ is orthogonal to every  {\it right} eigenvector with a different eigenvalue $\lambda_m$.
This is because
$$
\lambda_n {\bf v}_n^\dagger {\bf u}_m= ({\bf v}_n^\dagger  {\bf M}){\bf u}_m={\bf v}_n^\dagger ( {\bf M}{\bf u}_m) = \lambda_m  {\bf v}_n^\dagger {\bf u}_m,
$$
so
$$
0=(\lambda_n-\lambda_m)  {\bf v}_n^\dagger {\bf u}_m.
$$
This equation yields  a    proof of the equality of the left and right eigenvalues  that does not require an appeal to the finite-dimensional notion of a characteristic polynomial: if   ${\bf u}_m$ did   not have a corresponding ${\bf v}_m$ with the same eigenvalue  then ${\bf u}_m$ would   be perpendicular to all vectors   in $V$  --- in contradiction with the non-degeneracy of the inner product.

We may   choose the phases and normalization of the two eigenfunction sets so that
$$
{\bf v}_n^\dagger {\bf u}_m= \delta_{mn}
 $$
whence ${\bf v}_n^\dagger {\bf M} {\bf u}_m= \lambda_n \delta_{nm}$
which we can write as
$$
 {\bf V}^\dagger {\bf M} {\bf U}= {\rm diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots).
$$
Although neither of the   eigenvector families compose  an orthonormal set,  the matrices  ${\bf U}$ and ${\bf V}$ obey ${\bf V}^\dagger {\bf U}= {\mathbb I}$ so  we still have
$$
{\rm det\,}{\bf M}= {\rm det\,}({\bf V}^\dagger {\bf M} {\bf U}) = \prod_n\lambda_n.
$$

Comment: Why should we expect the eigenvalues of $\mathrm{i}\hat{D}$ to be distinct though? I know that distinct eigenvalues is the generic case, but nothing explicitly forbids it as far as I can see. Also, supposing this operator does have all distinct eigenvalues, what's to say that $V^\dagger U=1$, and not that $V^\dagger U$ is a projector (i.e. equal to 1 on a subspace but zero everywhere else)? We know that the left and right eigenvectors are mutually orthogonal, but why are they complete together?

Comment: I don't know enough about the infinite dimensional case to be useful, but in the finite case non-degeneracy of the eigenvalues  means that the characteristic polynomial has no repeated roots. In that case one can use it to write the identity operator as a sum of projectors onto the eigenvalue spaces. Thus any vector can be written as a sum of eigenvectors, which means that the eigenvectors are complete.

Comment: While that's true I don't understand how it could help establish whether $\mathrm{i}\hat{D}$ is complete.

Comment: Agreed.  Both Nakahara and Fujikawa's accounts just assume, as do most physicists,  that what is true for the finite systems continues to work  for the infinite case. After all ,a proper definition of the functional determinant is quite technical as the operators are not Hilbert-Schmidt or anything nice.